# JS, Jquery, Full calendar, student

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JS and even newer to Jquery and fullcalendar. I have created a calendar that works fine on a page by itself. I am trying to combine this code with another page and I can't get the calendar to render.

First I include some files:

```
<link href='/Include/fullcalendar-2.6.1/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
<link href='/Include/fullcalendar-2.6.1/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print'/>
<script src='/Include/fullcalendar-2.6.1/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='/Include/fullcalendar-2.6.1/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='/nclude/fullcalendar-2.6.1/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/include/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
```

My calendar code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: '2017-02-01',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [

            {
                id: 200,
                title: 'Weekly System\nBackup',
                url: '/images/backup.jpg',
                start: '2017-01-29'
            },
            {
                id: 200,
                title: 'Weekly System\nBackup',
                url: '/images/backup.jpg',
                start: '2017-02-05'
            },
            {
                id: 200,
                title: 'Weekly System\nBackup',
                url: '/images/backup.jpg',
                start: '2017-02-12'
            },
            {
                id: 200,
                title: 'Weekly System\nBackup',
                url: '/images/backup.jpg',
                start: '2017-02-19'
            },
            {
                id: 200,
                title: 'Weekly System\nBackup',
                url: '/images/backup.jpg',
                start: '2017-02-26'
            },
            {
                id: 200,
                title: 'Weekly System\nBackup',
                url: '/images/backup.jpg',
                start: '2017-03-05'
            },
            {
                title: 'Snow Break',
                url:   'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SxqmPdIxh8s',
                start: '2017-02-10',
                end:   '2017-02-15'
            },
            {
                title: 'C# Quiz',
                url:   '/images/quiz.jpg',
                start: '2017-02-15T11:30:00',
                end:   '2017-02-15T12:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Snow day 4',
                url: '/images/day4.jpg',
                start: '2017-02-16'
            },
            {
                title: 'SOG3 Due',
                url:  '/images/sog3.jpg',
                start: '2017-02-17'
            },
            {
                title: 'Started SOG4',
                url:  '/images/sog4.jpg',
                start: '2017-02-17'
            },
            {
                title: 'Winter Sale!',
                url:  '/SOG4/index.htm',
                start: '2017-02-28'
            }

        ]
    });

});
```

I donn't think there are any problems here as it works on the first page.

I include some inline styles:

```
body {
    margin: 40px 10px;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

finally the HTML:

```
<div id="Content">
    <p>Test</p>
    <div id='calendar'></div>   
</div>
```

Test shows up where it should, but no calendar. I am sorry for all the code, but I am a student and I can't understand why this is not working. Thanks for looking. Any advice would be greatly apprieciated.

Comment: In the documentation page, it says you must include jquery before you include moment and fullcalendar.js
`<link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
<script src='lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>`
It looks like you are including jquery after instead of before.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.

Comment: I'm not sure that will solve it, I just realized it looks like there is a jquery file specifically for the calendar library.

Comment: No, you are right, that did not solve it, but I appreciate the input.

Comment: ah, the jquery.min.js file? do I only need the one reference?

Comment: I just downloaded the library, replaced your header includes with the ones in documentation (leaving out your custom styling) at the moment and it worked fine. I believe they include a standard jquery library with their library, so yes you should only need the one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have typos in the 3rd and 4th script tags

```
<script src='/nclude/fullcalendar-2.6.1/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
```

(you typed `nclude` instead of `Include`). Try fixing that and see if it works.

Comment: I can't thank you enough, I probably would not have spotted that until tomorrow! That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: '2017-02-01',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [

            {
                id: 200,
                title: 'Weekly System\nBackup',
                url: '/images/backup.jpg',
                start: '2017-01-29'
            },
            {
                id: 200,
                title: 'Weekly System\nBackup',
                url: '/images/backup.jpg',
                start: '2017-02-05'
            },
            {
                id: 200,
                title: 'Weekly System\nBackup',
                url: '/images/backup.jpg',
                start: '2017-02-12'
            },
            {
                id: 200,
                title: 'Weekly System\nBackup',
                url: '/images/backup.jpg',
                start: '2017-02-19'
            },
            {
                id: 200,
                title: 'Weekly System\nBackup',
                url: '/images/backup.jpg',
                start: '2017-02-26'
            },
            {
                id: 200,
                title: 'Weekly System\nBackup',
                url: '/images/backup.jpg',
                start: '2017-03-05'
            },
            {
                title: 'Snow Break',
                url:   'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SxqmPdIxh8s',
                start: '2017-02-10',
                end:   '2017-02-15'
            },
            {
                title: 'C# Quiz',
                url:   '/images/quiz.jpg',
                start: '2017-02-15T11:30:00',
                end:   '2017-02-15T12:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Snow day 4',
                url: '/images/day4.jpg',
                start: '2017-02-16'
            },
            {
                title: 'SOG3 Due',
                url:  '/images/sog3.jpg',
                start: '2017-02-17'
            },
            {
                title: 'Started SOG4',
                url:  '/images/sog4.jpg',
                start: '2017-02-17'
            },
            {
                title: 'Winter Sale!',
                url:  '/SOG4/index.htm',
                start: '2017-02-28'
            }

        ]
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html><head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
<script src='lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script src='test.js'></script> // this is the file which includes your jquery, call it whatever you like
</head>
<body>
    
<div id="Content">
    <p>Test</p>
    <div id='calendar'></div>   
</div>

</body>
</html>
```